# Status bar is not changing it's orientation

Tags: ios, uiview, orientation, statusbar

Hi I'm using the following code to rotate the orientation of the screen programmatically, without rotating the real device.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown animated:NO];
```

It rotates everything except the status bar. Can you please tell me, how can I rotate everything on the screen programmatically?

Comment: You have hardcoded UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown  - why not take dynamically orientation when it's chaning ?

Comment: It's my client's requirement. Real device is not rotated, only the whole screen.

Comment: Where are you calling above setStatusBarOrientation method?

Comment: If I am not misinterpreting your question, you have mentioned that everything is rotated except status bar, right?

Comment: Yes. you are right. Everything is rotating upside down except the status bar.

Comment: Are you targeting iOS 6.0 version?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43767/discussion-between-ldindu-and-farhad-rubel)

Answer (score 0):

Implement this in your viewController

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
```

Your root view controller required to answer NO to shouldAutorotate for your app to respond setStatusBarOrientation:animated method.